# See Javadocs for basic classes in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Is there a way to see/attach the Javadocs and/or source code for basic classes (like String) in IntelliJ?

I'm using IntelliJ Community Edition 11.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you add new **JSDK**, sources are configured automatically:

[image: JSDK Sourcepath]

If your JDK installation is missing sources, you will need to download and configure them manually. Mac users should refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4147499/104891).

When you have sources attached to the JSDK configuration, navigating to the class will open source code instead of decompiled stub and you can also use `View` | `Quick Documentation` based on the javadoc in the source files.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at productivity tips:

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/tips/index.html